# How to get the file path without the file name in php?

Tags: php

For example this is $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] output:

```
example.com/foldername/subfolder/controller/index.php
```

I want to end up with example.com/foldername/subfolder/controller/

Thanks..

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php, http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.dirname.php

Comment: http://php.net/pathinfo

Comment: @CBroe dirname(example.com/foldername/subfolder/controller/index.php) solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

```
<?php
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');

echo $path_parts['dirname'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['basename'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['extension'], "\n";
echo $path_parts['filename'], "\n"; // since PHP 5.2.0
?>
```

The output for that would be

```
/www/htdocs/inc
lib.inc.php
php
lib.inc
```

So, in short, you could use `$path_parts['dirname']`.

Answer (score 0):

```
print_r( $_SERVER );
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php

```
PATH_TRANSLATED or __DIR__
```

Lots of options =)

Answer (score 0):

Add the two together to get

```
$url = "http://". $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
```